# v-model inside loop showing the wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Im using vue version *2.6.14* in development
and I do looping *array of object* data and use v-model inside those loop and the idea user should have ability to add or remove the data dynamically but when I add or remove
the array the v-model not showing correct data. for example if I fill the object on array index 1, the rest object have same value. please see the following code
and screenshot:

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row mb-3" v-for="(i, idx) in products" :key="idx">
    <div>
      <button @click="addRow" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
      add
      </button>
      <button @click="removeRow(idx)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">
      remove
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <input v-model="products[idx].name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
      <input v-model="products[idx].category" type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="category">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      products: [{
        name: null,
        category: null
      }],
      product: {
        name: null,
        category: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function(){
        this.products.push(this.product);
    },
    removeRow: function(index){
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

and here the screenshot
[image]

And the expectation is the field in the blue box (blue box on the picture) shouldn't follow the red box

here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6t502y7/16/)

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessary to access the item using index inside `v-for` instead you can use the iterator itself

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row mb-3" v-for="(product, idx) in products" :key="idx"> <!-- line changed -->
    <div>
      <button @click="addRow" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
      add
      </button>
      <button @click="removeRow(idx)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">
      remove
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <input v-model="product.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name"> <!-- line changed -->
    </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
      <input v-model="product.category" type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="category"> <!-- line changed -->
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Also modify the `addRow` method to be

```
methods: {
addRow(){
        this.products.push({...this.product}); // Using rest operator to create a new reference
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Amaarockz its works. But why should we spread `{...this.product}` object instead of just pushing `this.product` into arrray?

Comment: if you don't use spread, everytime when you push it, it goes with the same reference. Therefore when you type name in one input field it gets reflected to other rows as well since they share a common reference